# Trigger script on certain document library event?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Is there a way of triggering a script on certain event in a document library in SharePoint?

How can one control those events? can they be controlled at all? are they even created by SharePoint?

I'm specifically interested on converting some files into pdf upon they're received in the document library in order to merge all them later on certain user's demand. I think it's going to be easier if this is achieved using ASP.net.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those are called "Event Handlers" or "Event Receivers" in SharePoint.

- [Event Handlers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx)
- [Understanding Event Receivers](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/understanding-sharepoint-event-receivers/)